# Deselecting from a listbox in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I'm just wondering how I can deselect from a list box in thinter. Whenever I click on something in a list box, it gets highlighted and it gets underlined, but when I click off of the screen towards the side, the list box selection stays highlighted. Even when I click a button, the selection still stays underlined. For ex: in the example code below, I can't click off of the list box selection after clicking on one of them.

```
from tkinter import *

def Add():
   listbox.insert(END, textVar.get())


root = Tk()

textVar = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable = textVar)
add = Button(root, text="add", command = Add)
frame = Frame(root, height=100, width=100, bg="blue")
listbox = Listbox(root, height=5)
add.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)
listbox.grid(row=1, column=0)
frame.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's the normal behavior of the listbox. If you want to change that you could call the clear function every time the listbox left focus:

```
listbox.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda e: listbox.selection_clear(0, END))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the selectmode parameter on the Listbox widget. 
You can click the selected item again and it will clear the selection.

See the effbot link:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm

```
listbox = Listbox(root, height=5, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to create the functionality needed within the Listbox widget so that when a user clicks either back on the same item in the Listbox or elsewhere on screen the currently selected item is deselected. The solution came out to be quite simple.

Firsly I created a binding so that when the left mouse button is pressed anywhere on the window a function to deselect the list box is executed.

```
root.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', deselect_item)
```

I then created a variable to store the value of the last listbox item to be selected and initialised its value to `None`

```
previous_selected = None
```

Then I defined the function to deselect the listbox as follows. Firsly the new item (what item the user has just clicked on) is selected and compared to the previously selected item. If this is true then the user has clicked on an already highlighted item in the listbox and so the listbox's selection is cleared, removing the selected item. Finally, the function updates the previously selected box to the current selected box.

```
def deselect_item(event):
    if listbox.curselection() == previous_selected:
            listbox.selection_clear(0, tkinter.END)
    previous_selected = listbox.curselection()
```

A full working example of this (in python 3.8.0) is shown below:

```
import tkinter

class App(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.previous_selected = None

        self.listbox = tkinter.Listbox(self)
        self.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.deselect_item)

        self.listbox.insert(tkinter.END, 'Apple')
        self.listbox.insert(tkinter.END, 'Orange')
        self.listbox.insert(tkinter.END, 'Pear')

        self.listbox.pack()

    def deselect_item(self, event):
        if self.listbox.curselection() == self.previous_selected:
                self.listbox.selection_clear(0, tkinter.END)
        self.previous_selected = self.listbox.curselection()

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```